# Does a 1x1 convolutional Layer have a bias (Inception Modules)?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

This question is regarding to the 1x1 convolutional layer idea from the paper
"Going Deeper with Convolutions"(https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842) that describe the idea of so called inception modules.

Does the 1x1 convolutional layer have a bias? Probably not, but since e.g. a 3x3 convolutional layers has a bias the term does "convolutional layer" does not quiet fit perfectly and is irritating.

Comment: Can you clarify why the term "convolutional layer" doesn't fit in this case? This will help improve the quality of answers to this question.

Comment: It doesn't have a bias like a "usual" convolutional layer has.

Comment: The bias term is optional, it’s become quite frequent to turn these off by default. Although no bias exists, it is still convolutional by nature — the outputs of the layer are guided by local patches (in this case, single pixel values)